# How to get set temperature?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, smart-device, nest-device-access

I would like to get the current temperature set on heat mode of the Nest thermostat (not the ambient measure temperature).

Is there a way to do that from Google Scripts?

I looked at the Google Apps scripts documentation but found nothing about this.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/nest-thermostat/

Comment: I alread have a script that behaves more or less like this, but even in that example, the setpoint temperature is not stored somewhere.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand you correctly - you wish to retrieve the current temperature from the thermostat? If so, check the `Step 17` part of the link I posted earlier. To be more specific - lines 74 and 75, which should return temperature in Celsius and Fahrenheit. If you're not after the current temperature, but the one you've set manually, try `alert`ing or otherwise logging all of the properties of the response you get back from the device.

Comment: Indeed, I would like to get the temperature I have set manually. Could you please give me more details about alert? Which command would it be?

Comment: I did it! I used this code (by chance):

 
`var settemp = device['traits']['sdm.devices.traits.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint']['heatCelsius'];
Logger.log('settemp' + settemp);`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I did it! I used this code (by chance):

```
var settemp = device['traits']['sdm.devices.traits.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint']['heatCelsius']; 
Logger.log('settemp' + settemp);
```